Ghost-free quadratic gravity
This is an question about how to write an equivalent of "energy-squared" in terms of a gravitational metric. i.e. a spin-2 term that approximates to the spin-0 term $\int (\nabla^\mu \phi \nabla_\mu \phi)^2 dx^4$. Another way of asking the question is, is there a diffeomorphism invariant action containing 4th powers of the first derivative of the metric and no second derivatives?
So first we know:
$\int\sqrt{-g}R dx^4$ is to $\int \phi\nabla^2\phi dx^4$
as $\int \sqrt{-g}R^*dx^4$ is to $\int \nabla^\mu \phi \nabla_\mu \phi dx^4$
Where symbolically it is something like (ignoring indices) $R^* = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\Gamma\partial (\sqrt{-g}g) + \Gamma^2$
i.e. $R^*$ is got by integration by parts of $R$ so that it contains no second derivatives (e.g. $\partial \Gamma$ terms.). It would not be diffeomorphism invariant on it's own, only as part of an integral.
My question is:
$\int \sqrt{-g}R^2 dx^4$ is to $\int(\phi\nabla^2\phi)^2 dx^4$
as $?$ is to $\int (\nabla^\mu \phi \nabla_\mu \phi)^2 \phi dx^4$
I don't think the answer could be $\int \sqrt{-g}(R^*)^2 dx^4$ as this probably isn't diffeomorphism invariant. If it is that would mean that it would be equivalent to $\int \sqrt{-g}(a R^2 + b R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}d)x^4$ by integration by parts.
The reason I'm asking is that I've seen a theory like $\int f(\nabla^\mu \phi \nabla_\mu \phi)dx^4$ and want to find an equivalent theory involving $R$. Perhaps it is impossible?
Edit: From one of the comments one could do:
$$L =\sqrt{-g}\sqrt{\Lambda^2 +  R^2- 4R^{ab}R_{ab}+R^{abcd}R_{abcd}} $$
$$\approx \sqrt{-g}\sqrt{\Lambda^2 + g^{-6}(\partial g)^4}$$
$$\approx (?) \sqrt{-g} g^{-3}(\partial g)^2$$
which would use the Gauss-Bonnet term but be non-vanishing but isn't quite what I want as the quartic term (when written as a series) would still vanish. But the octic term might not!(?) (square of gauss-bonnet) Therefor I think I can solve it for $(\partial g)^2$, $(\partial g)^{4n}$ with $n>1$ so far...
Edit 2
If Lovelock theory is correct then if $\int \sqrt{-g}(R^*)^2d^4x$ is diffeomorphic then it must equal the Gauss-Bonnet term.(??)

Are you perhaps looking for Lovelock's gravity? Note, that in 4D the quadratic in curvature term is absent (or rather it is  topological).

Are you looking for $f(R)$ gravity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F(R)_gravity ?

Similar but one which involves only first derivatives of the metric tensor. That involves second derivatives.

@bob I'm only taking a guess, but I think much of the difficulty with quadratic gravity (i.e., considering these higher order terms) is precisely that they involve second derivatives. Remember that $R$ itself already contains second derivatives of the metric.

If there is such an action, you probably have to subtract the second derivatives by hand. In the luckiest of cases, this can be done by using a boundary term (which is the role of the Gibbons-Hawking-York term in pure GR and what lies behind your definition of $R^*$). I find it unlikely that the second derivatives in quadratic gravity are merely boundary terms

@NíckolasAlves Thanks, I always wondered if the Hawking boundary term was necessary if they defined the action in terms of $R^*$ (first derivative only form) instead of $R$.

Minor comment to the post (v8): Note that the standard notation is $d^4x$ not $dx^4$.
